# ExtJS 6: Parse url paramaters from rest pathname

Tags: extjs6, extjs6-classic, extjs7

Is there a inbuilt library in ExtJS v6 or v7 that could help in parsing rest style url pathname. For example a pathname `"/abc/123/def/456/geh"` should return `{ abc_id: 123, id: 456 }

Answer (score 0):

No, because REST-style URLs are for web services, not single-page apps (SPA). A SPA is intended to be represented by a single URL. If you try to use REST-style URLs, the browser will reload the page, restarting the app.

Navigation within that URL can be done via routes (done in the anchor portion of the URL, after the #). For more information on using routes, check [the documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.2.0/guides/application_architecture/router.html).

Comment: Yes, when we are talking about SPA, url does mean after hash or bang sign to navigate withing app. Anyhow I have figured that out. Thanks for the response, appreciate your help